# JOIN, GROUP BY, COUNT AND CASE in one query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:
1)Planets
       id
       name
       from_sun 
       moons_number  //integer
       planet_class
2)Moons
       id
       name
       planet_id  //is equal to id of planet from previous table
       is_major

The task is:

Fetch the following data:
1)the name of the planet,
2)the number of moons of the planet according to the table moons,
3)the number of moons of the planet according to the table planets,
4)the column named comparison with values ‘+’ or '-' (the result of comparison of the values in columns in 2 and 3, ‘+’ if they are equal and '-' if they differ).

Order the result set by the result of comparison and then by the name of the planet. 
Note: Include the planets with no moons.

This is my attempt to do it:

```
SELECT p.name AS planet
      ,COUNT(m.id) AS m1
      ,p.moons_number AS m2 
      ,CASE WHEN m1=m2 THEN '+'ELSE '-' END AS comparison 
FROM planets AS p
LEFT JOIN moons AS m 
ON p.id=m.planet_id
GROUP BY planet
ORDER BY comparison, planet
```

I’ve tried many times, but it refuses to work
Local ELITE, I i kneel down and ask for your help!
COUNTING ON YOU ^^

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your table structure in a coherent fashion.  In the SELECT you post the CASE statement looks invalid, the GROUP BY appears to be incomplete, and I don't think you can ORDER BY an alias in the manner.

Comment: I had no access to PC, when was writing a question so sorry) Luckily Jaime Drq has already helped) Thx for intention ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query could work.

```
SELECT 
  p.name AS planet, 
  COUNT(m.id) AS m1, 
  max(p.moons_number) AS m2, 
  CASE WHEN COUNT(m.id)=max(p.moons_number) THEN '+' ELSE '-' END AS comparison 
FROM planets AS p 
  LEFT JOIN moons AS m 
    ON p.id=m.planet_id 
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY 4,1;
```

Because of the planet should have just one value for `moons_number`, you can just do a `max` to get this value and then `group by planet` will be valid.
For the `case when`, you can compare then these 2 values now with this little change.